# How do I convert DAML tuples received via the DA Ledger API into Java pairs?

Tags: daml

I have written a DAML model that generates a list of tuples, e.g. `[(Int, Text)]`. I receive this data via the DA Ledger API - how do I convert it to `List<Pair<Long, String>>` in Java?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Java depends on whether you are working with the raw compiled Protobuf types, or the wrapped types provided by the Java Language Bindings.

Objects returned by the API are represented using three major types:

- `Record`
- `RecordField`
- `Value`.

Simplifying somewhat,  a`Record` is a list of `RecordField`, a `RecordField` is a label and a `Value` and a `Value` can be one of many things, including an `Int64`, a `String`, a `Record`, or a `List`. Tuples like `(Int, Text)` have special notation in DAML, but are represented as normal `Record` objects in the API.

Assuming you are using the types compiled from the protobuf definitions, and have got your hands on a `com.digitalasset.ledger.api.v1.ValueOuterClass.Value` representing the `[(Int, Text)]`, you need to do the following:

1. Use `Value::getList` and `ValueOuterClass.List::getElementsList` to unwrap the `Value` into a `List<Value>`.
2. Unwrap each `Value` in the list via `Value::getRecord` to get a `List<Record>`
3. Extract each record’s two fields using `Record::getFields` to get `List<Pair<RecordField, RecordField>>`
4. Extract the values from `RecordFields` with `RecordFields::getValue`, giving `List<Pair<Value, Value>>`
5. Extract the `Int64`, which is an alias for `long`, and `String` from the `Value` objects to get the final `List<Pair<Long, String>>`

Steps 2. - 4. can be accomplished neatly using Java’s streaming interface. The code shown is for the raw gRPC types, starting from a `com.digitalasset.ledger.api.v1.ValueOuterClass.Value`:

```
import com.digitalasset.ledger.api.v1.ValueOuterClass;
import static java.util.AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Demo {
    static SimpleImmutableEntry<ValueOuterClass.RecordField, ValueOuterClass.RecordField> EntryFromTuple(ValueOuterClass.Record tupleRecord) {
        return new SimpleImmutableEntry<>(tupleRecord.getFields(0), tupleRecord.getFields(1));
    }

    static class SimpleImmutableEntryMap<S, T, U, V> implements Function<SimpleImmutableEntry<S, T>, SimpleImmutableEntry<U, V>> {
        Function<S, U> mapFst;
        Function<T, V> mapSnd;

        public SimpleImmutableEntryMap(Function<S, U> mapFst, Function<T, V> mapSnd) {
            this.mapFst = mapFst;
            this.mapSnd = mapSnd;
        }

        @Override
        public SimpleImmutableEntry<U, V> apply(SimpleImmutableEntry<S, T> stEntry) {
            return new SimpleImmutableEntry<> (mapFst.apply(stEntry.getKey()), mapSnd.apply(stEntry.getValue()));
        }
    }

    static List<SimpleImmutableEntry<Long, String>> mapTuple(ValueOuterClass.Value v) {
        return v.getList().getElementsList().stream()
                .map(ValueOuterClass.Value::getRecord)
                .map(Demo::EntryFromTuple)
                .map(new SimpleImmutableEntryMap<>(ValueOuterClass.RecordField::getValue, ValueOuterClass.RecordField::getValue))
                .map(new SimpleImmutableEntryMap<>(ValueOuterClass.Value::getInt64, ValueOuterClass.Value::getText))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Assuming that you have the following daml template:

```
template ListOfTuples
  with
    party : Party
    listOfTuples : [(Int, Text)]
  where
    signatory party
```

that has been transformed to a `com.daml.ledger.javaapi.data.Record` with the java api, you can convert it to a `List<Pair<Long, String>>` by treating the tuples in the list also as `Record`s:

```
import java.util.List;
import javafx.util.Pair;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import com.daml.ledger.javaapi.data.Record;

public void parseListOfTuples(Record record) {

  List<Pair<Long, String>> listOfTuples =
     record.getFields().get(1).getValue().asList().get().getValues().stream()
             .map(t -> {
                 List<Record.Field> tuple = t.asRecord().get().getFields();
                 return new Pair<>(
                         tuple.get(0).getValue().asInt64().get().getValue(),
                         tuple.get(1).getValue().asText().get().getValue());
             })
             .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```